# Is polynomial regression typically linear or non-linear?

Tags: polynomials, definition, regression

Here's my doubt:

> When we say polynomial regression, do we usually mean linear or non-linear?

A simple answer would be very helpful.

---

<sub><sup>This is not a duplicate question. I've read through similar questions and require clarification on the **nuances** of the terminology.</sup></sub>

Comment: This question is probably too broad to receive a useful answer.

Comment: @dbx Thought so... Ok, I'll delete everything except the main question I have.

Comment: In regression, linearity is with respect to parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polynomial regression usually stands for the fitting of a polynomial to a set of $(x,y)$ points, which is a linear problem when solved by least-squares.

Answer (score 1):

No. As was already pointed out - the linearity in regression model is defined w.r.t. the parameters $\beta$ and not the variables $x$. Formally, if the gradient vector of (the conditional expectation of the model) is independent of any unknown terms - then it is linear, otherwise non-linear. Namely, for a polynomial regression 
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \sum_j^p \beta_j x_{i}^ j + \epsilon_i,
$$ 
the gradient w.r.t. the $\beta$ is 
$$
\nabla_{\beta} \mathbb{E}[y|x]=(1, x, x^2,...,x^p)^T,
$$
that is independent of any unknown factors, hence the model is "linear".